# Refer to an item in `dirs`

Tags: bash, zsh, directory, pushd

I use `pushd` to work with multiple directories in `bash` and `zsh`. I've aliased `dirs` to `dirs -v` so that I get an ordered list when I want to see what's on the directory stack:

```
chb$ dirs
0  /Volumes/banister/grosste_daever_gh/2013-03-27/reader
1  /tmp/20130618202713/Library/Internet Plug-Ins
2  ~/code/foo/view/static/css
3  ~/Downloads
```

Is there a way (either in `bash` or `zsh`) that I can refer to one of the directories listed on the command line using an alias for its position on the stack? For example, instead of typing:

```
chb$ cp ~/code/foo/view/static/css/baz.css ~/code/bar/view/static/css/
```

I'd type:

```
chb$ cp <2>baz.css ~/code/bar/view/static/css/
```

...or something *like* that, maybe using a dollar sign and a variable name instead of `<n>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bash exposes the directory stack in the [`DIRSTACK` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Directory-Stack.html#The-Directory-Stack). You can also use the command `dirs +2` to refer to the second entry on the stack.

More conveniently, `~1` through `~9` refer to the nine topmost entries on the stack. So your example would translate to

```
chb$ cp ~2/baz.css ~/code/bar/view/static/css/
```

Zsh has [the same *~n* facility](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/zsh/dir_stack.html), and the stack is exposed through an array called `dirstack`. Bash's `dirs +2` is zsh's `print -r ~2` or `print -r $dirstack[2]`.

Comment: This answer just begs for some examples!

Comment: @Johan better now? Thanks for prodding me to expand!

Comment: Good but what about a $DIRSTACK[2] example ?

Comment: Probably good enough to have in your cimment (-:

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in bash:

```
cp $(dirs +2) ~/code/bar/view/static/css/
```

or even simpler:

```
cp ~2 ~/code/bar/view/static/css/
```