# Using pushd and popd

Tags: pushd

Say I do the following:

```
cd ~
pushd .
cd /bin/
pushd .
dirs
"/bin/ ~/
cd ~/Downloads/
pushd .
dirs
~/Downloads /bin/ ~"
```

How would I `popd` back to something a while ago, say from downloads to the home directory`~`?

Comment: So what would I do `popd 2` to go to something that I `pushd`'d two times ago?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your shell, for `zsh` you can just use `cd -N` to change to your `Nth` previous directory.

For bash you can use for example `dirs` to get a directory name. You can use that to do something like `cd "$(dirs -N)"` which will go the the `Nth` previous directory, just like the zsh example above.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for, though it is a lot to type. I'll have to alias it once I figure out how to use arguments in aliases.

Comment: look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80692/refer-to-an-item-in-dirs and the answers there is a shortcut

Comment: So it would be `cd ~2`, if I understand right?

Comment: After testing, it looks like that's how it works. Thanks.