# To get in variable, a directory've been pushd

Tags: bash, variable, stack

How do I use, i.e. to have in bash variable, a directory just've been pushd, and not to do popd command ?

Comment: Does this help? [Refer to an item in `dirs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80692/refer-to-an-item-in-dirs)

Comment: `$OLDPWD` is a magic shell variable .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know just the name of the previous directory you can issue

```
% echo $OLDPWD
```

If you want to go to that directory, you can simply do

```
% cd -
```

which will automatically changedir to `$OLDPWD`

If you want to the full directory stack that you have created using pushd-popd

```
% dirs -v
```

this will print the directory index alongside the directory name

You can jump to a directory by just giving

```
% pushd +N
```

where N is the index of the directory.

Comment: `echo $OLDPWD` will fail if any of the directories in that path contain whitespace. Double-quite the variable when you use it (as you should do for any variable), like `echo "$OLDPWD"`

Answer (score 0):

[In Bash, there's the `DIRSTACK` array variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> `DIRSTACK`
> An array variable containing the current contents of the
> directory stack. Directories appear in the stack in the order they are
> displayed by the dirs builtin.

The last one pushed is `"${DIRSTACK[0]}"`, the second at index `[1]`, etc.

```
me@hostname /tmp$ pushd a
/tmp/a /tmp
me@hostname /tmp/a$ pushd /tmp/b
/tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp
me@hostname /tmp/b$ dirs
/tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp
me@hostname /tmp/b$ declare -p DIRSTACK
declare -a DIRSTACK=([0]="/tmp/b" [1]="/tmp/a" [2]="/tmp")
```